# Cannot connect to FTP server from external host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ftp

I have a FTP server (vsftpd) setuped on a Linux box (Ubuntu server). When I try to connect with a computer on the same network everything works fine as expected.

But as soon the IP is external it won't connect..

I first assumed the port was blocked, but then:

```
localserver:$ sudo tail -f /var/log/vsftpd.log
Wed Jan 13 14:21:17 2010 [pid 2407] CONNECT: Client "xxx.xxx.107.4"
remotemachine:$ netcat svn-motion.no-ip.biz 21
220 FTP Server
```

And it hangs there.  Do any ports other than 21 need to be open?

Answer (score 1):

When putting an FTP server behind a NAT, you not only have to forward port 21/TCP to the server, you also need a NAT gateway that has an FTP [ALG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-level_gateway) that supports FTP servers behind the NAT (note: this is a rare feature, and rarely advertised on the box or on the tech specs page or even in the manual), and knows to watch the FTP control data stream for commands from clients that indicate the client wants the FTP server to use passive mode (where the FTP server starts listening for a data TCP connection on another port, sends that port number to the client, and passively waits for the client to initiate data TCP connection to the server). The FTP ALG has to watch for what port the server told the client to connect on, and then automatically create a temporary port forwarding entry to allow that connection to get to the server.

Basically, Passive mode FTP, which is great when the *client* is behind a NAT, is a big problem when the *server* is behind the NAT. If it turns out that your client is NOT behind a NAT, then tell your client to use traditional "active" mode FTP, and you don't need to have a sophisticated "server behind the NAT" FTP ALG in your NAT gateway.

Another option would be to make your FTP server be your DMZ host (a.k.a. "default host", "bastion host"). Since all unexpected incoming connection attempts are forwarded to the DMZ, all those passive mode FTP data TCP connections would automatically go do your FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is behind any type of firewall you may need to make sure the *remotemachine* is using FTP Passive mode.

Comment: sftp does not use multiple connection, it only use 21 and thus is passive by default.

Comment: if you are using SFTP then the default port would probably be 22

Comment: Oh, right.. when using ftp only I get "Unknown server error"

Comment: When using the IP directly it works ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to the server's external IP from an internal computer?  If so, and if you are using a typical home router in a NAT configuration, the problem may actually be the router.

Presumably you've configured the router to forward FTP to the Ubuntu server, and you're trying to test that this works.  But when you test the external IP directly from your internal network, your router has to support a "hairpin" route.  Your router must send traffic from an *internal* host, out through the *external* IP, back into the *external* IP, and finally forward that back to your server's *internal* IP -- all on the same device.  Most consumer routers don't handle this situation properly.

So you need test from a real external host.  You have several options:

- Use an internet port-testing service like [Can You See Me](http://www.canyouseeme.org/).
- Send your test traffic through a proxy.
- Have a friend test from their network.
- Find a local coffeeshop with WiFi and test from there.